# Interpreting nested mixed effects model output in R

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I'm having an issue interpreting the baseline coefficients within a nested mixed effects model.  I've fitted a model Test.Score ~ Subject + (1|School/Class) as class is nested within school.  When I look at the coefficients however using coef(model) they seem counter intuitive:

```
$`Class:School`
      (Intercept) SubjectMaths
1:A    82.73262    -4.108333
1:B    83.98870    -4.108333
1:C    82.26456    -4.108333
2:A    82.25383    -4.108333
2:B    78.22047    -4.108333
2:C    80.18982    -4.108333

$School
(Intercept) SubjectMaths
A    88.39636    -4.108333
B    77.74404    -4.108333
C    78.68460    -4.108333

attr(,"class")
[1] "coef.mer"
```

How can the class within school give values much lower than those just within school?  Data to replicate below:

```
Test.Score = c(94,88,86,90,94,87,87,92,89,92,87,94,93,91,89,92,91,
    91,95,91,82,84,90,81,92,89,85,94,88,94,94,94,86,94,93,84,82,
    92,92,83,89,83,81,87,84,80,81,83,88,82,81,90,82,85,87,82,86,
    84,87,88,82,91,95,77,88,87,79,75,91,77,82,91,95,92,89,83,79,
    90,83,83,82,79,79,78,83,82,81,77,80,79,84,83,81,78,77,75,76,
    76,84,75,78,78,71,79,70,75,75,78,76,71,76,76,73,71,80,70,71,
    78,71,74,76,74,74,77,81,78,79,76,82,79,80,73,72,83,72,81,81,
    72,79,74,67,75,71,66,65,71,73,69,65,67,71,72,68,73,65,65,74,
    67,72,72,82,70,72,86,89,87,87,88,74,92,70,89,86,63,68,74,88,
    71,88,91,76,86,75,79,76,69,86,71,78,67,67,73,69,81,79,78,80,
    72,81,69,72,75,76,68,72,78,78,77,71,73,70,77,75,75,69,77,74,
    76,68,78,76,75,68,74,69,78,76,70,79,78,67,65,86,88,65,88,73,
    66,65,85)
School = rep(c("A","B","C"), each = 80)
Class = rep(c("1","2"), each = 20,6)
Subject = rep(c("English","Maths"), each = 40, 3)
data = data.frame(Test.Score, School, Class, Subject)
data$Class = factor(data$Class)
mod = lmer(Test.Score ~ Subject + (1|School/Class), REML = F, 
    data = data)
coef(mod)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the coefficients listed for each random effect include *only* the effects of that particular random effect.  In particular, the level-2 `School:Class` coefficients reflect only the deviations of the Class within the School from the overall population mean - *not* the School-level effects as well. That may seem weird or wrong, but (1) you can get what you're looking for with `predict()` (see below) and (2) `lme4` doesn't really have an internal representation of "nesting", so it would be hard to determine in general which random effects should be included in a given set of coefficients (this is an explanation, not an excuse).

For what it's worth, `coef()` does work as you expect for models fitted with `nlme::lme` ...

```
library(lme4)
## using sum-to-zero contrasts for convenience
mod = lmer(Test.Score ~ Subject + (1|School/Class), REML = FALSE, 
           data = data, contrasts=list(Subject=contr.sum))
pframe <- with(data,expand.grid(School=levels(School),
                            Subject=levels(Subject),
                            Class=levels(Class)))
pframe$Test.Score <- predict(mod,newdata=pframe)
```

If you wanted the average Class value, you'd need to average the English and Maths scores ...

The same model in `nlme::lme`:

```
mod2 = nlme::lme(Test.Score ~ Subject, random = ~ 1|School/Class, method="ML",
    data = data, contrasts=list(Subject=contr.sum))
coef(mod2)         ## Class within School
coef(mod2,level=1) ## School-level
```

With some tedium (and tidyverse tools - this could be done in other ways as well), rearrange the coefficients for plotting:

```
rr2 <- tibble::rownames_to_column(coef(mod)[["Class:School"]])
rr2 <- dplyr::rename(rr2,Test.Score=`(Intercept)`)
rr2 <- tidyr::separate(rowname,data=rr2,into=c("Class","School"))
rr2$Subject <- NA

rr3 <- tibble::rownames_to_column(coef(mod)[["School"]])
rr3 <- dplyr::rename(rr3,Test.Score=`(Intercept)`,School=rowname)
rr3$Subject <- NA
rr3$Class <- 1.5
```

Plot everything together (data, predictions, coefficients):

```
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(data,aes(Class,Test.Score,colour=Subject))+
    geom_boxplot()+
    geom_point(data=pframe,size=3,shape=16,position=position_dodge(width=0.75))+
    facet_wrap(~School,labeller=label_both)+
    geom_point(data=rr2,size=3,shape=17)+
    geom_hline(yintercept=fixef(mod)["(Intercept)"],lty=2)+
    geom_point(data=rr3,size=5,shape=18)+
    theme(panel.spacing=grid::unit(0,"lines")) ## cosmetic
```

Coloured points are predictions; gray points are coefficients (triangle = class-level; diamond = school-level).

[image]

Comment: I've been trying to recreate this but excluding class and have been desperately failing. Would you please be able to show me the code for this without the school as another nested level? 

In my application I'm attempting to see the effect of School on Test.Scores given multiple observations per individual student. 

lmer(Test.Score ~ School+ (1|Subject), data=raw, REML = T, na.action=na.exclude) OR lme(Test.Score ~ School , random = ~ 1|School, method="REML", data = data, na.action = na.exclude)